# Sending value from several buttons to input with pure JS

Tags: javascript

I am very new at JS and are trying to figure something out:

I need to set a condition so that buttons in row 1 & 2 both needs to be clicked, when pressing submit I need to display their combined value into the < input >. For example it should show up something like this: "$40 by Person 2" This with **only** JS (no jQuery).

```
<div>
    <div>
      <span>Row 1</span>
      <button>$10</button>
      <button>$20</button>
      <button>$30</button>
      <button>$40</button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
      <span>Row 2</span>
      <button>Person 1</button>
      <button>Person 2</button>
      <button>Person 3</button>
      <button>Person 4</button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <button>Submit</button>
    <div><input></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is it necessary that you have to do it with buttons only? you can do this by giving two <select> fields.

Comment: Yes unfortunately they need to be buttons.. thats why Ive had a hard time finding examples for this.

Comment: or lets say if it can't be done, then it can be anything that I can easily style as a btn with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only JavaScript you could use something like ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7a9j/1/)):

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button'),
    input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0],
    first, second;

for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(this.firstChild.nodeValue.charAt(0)=='$'){
            first = this.firstChild.nodeValue;
        }else if(this.firstChild.nodeValue !== 'Submit'){
            second = this.firstChild.nodeValue;
        }else{
            if(first==null || second==null){
                alert('You must click a button from each row');
            }else{
                input.value = first+' by '+second;
            }
        } 
    });
}
```

This depends on the final button called "Submit", and the first row buttons starting with $. If that won't be always the case consider adding a class to differentiate each row.

Comment: Thanks looks great! but I need some condition or something so that both buttons need to be clicked in order for the submit to display the values.